# Cannot display values when a link is clicked from with Jquery/Javascript Notification Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I downloaded this popup notification from http://www.encodedna.com/jquery/create-a-facebook-like-notifications-using-jquery-css.htm.

I want to use it to display value eg. (11) in a modal popup when a link is clicked.

When I Click the link on the body of the page it works fine and displays value 11. The problem is that when 
I click the link from within the popup notification menu, it does not show any value. It seems that Document() functions for notification Popup is conflicting
with Document() function that helps to display data.

(NB: if you first click link on the body and then click on the link inside the notification popup it shows values)

**I only want to display data by clicking the link from within the Notification Popup Menu.** Thanks

Here is the Javascript for Menu Notification Popup

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // ANIMATEDLY DISPLAY THE NOTIFICATION COUNTER.
        $('#noti_Counter')
            .css({ opacity: 0 })
            .text('7')              // ADD DYNAMIC VALUE (YOU CAN EXTRACT DATA FROM DATABASE OR XML).
            .css({ top: '-10px' })
            .animate({ top: '-2px', opacity: 1 }, 500);

        $('#noti_Button').click(function () {

            // TOGGLE (SHOW OR HIDE) NOTIFICATION WINDOW.
            $('#notifications').fadeToggle('fast', 'linear', function () {
                if ($('#notifications').is(':hidden')) {
                    $('#noti_Button').css('background-color', '#2E467C');
                }
                else $('#noti_Button').css('background-color', '#FFF');        // CHANGE BACKGROUND COLOR OF THE BUTTON.
            });

            $('#noti_Counter').fadeOut('slow');                 // HIDE THE COUNTER.

            return false;
        });

        // HIDE NOTIFICATIONS WHEN CLICKED ANYWHERE ON THE PAGE.
        $(document).click(function () {
            $('#notifications').hide();

            // CHECK IF NOTIFICATION COUNTER IS HIDDEN.
            if ($('#noti_Counter').is(':hidden')) {
                // CHANGE BACKGROUND COLOR OF THE BUTTON.
                $('#noti_Button').css('background-color', '#2E467C');
            }
        });

        $('#notifications').click(function () {
            return false;       // DO NOTHING WHEN CONTAINER IS CLICKED.
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the javascript that displays data in a modal when clicked

```
<script>

$(document).on("click", ".opendata", function () {

     var myuserid1a = $(this).data('userid1a');

     $(".modal-body_chat #b_userid1a").val( myuserid1a );
});


</script>
```

here is the entire code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<style>
    ul {
        display:block;
        background:#45619D;
        list-style:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:12px 10px;
        height:21px;
    }
    ul li {
        float:left;
        font:13px helvetica;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin:3px 0;
    }
    ul li a {
        color:#black;
        text-decoration:none;
        padding:6px 15px;
        cursor:pointer;
    }


    /* A CIRCLE LIKE BUTTON IN THE TOP MENU. */
    #noti_Button {
        width:202px;
        height:22px;
        line-height:22px;
        border-radius:50%;
        -moz-border-radius:50%; 
        -webkit-border-radius:50%;
        background:#FFF;
        margin:-3px 10px 0 10px;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    /* THE POPULAR RED NOTIFICATIONS COUNTER. */
    #noti_Counter {
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        background:#E1141E;
        color:#FFF;
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight:normal;
        padding:1px 3px;
        margin:-8px 0 0 25px;
        border-radius:2px;
        -moz-border-radius:2px; 
        -webkit-border-radius:2px;
        z-index:1;
    }

    /* THE NOTIFICAIONS WINDOW. THIS REMAINS HIDDEN WHEN THE PAGE LOADS. */
    #notifications {
        display:none;
        width:430px;
        position:absolute;
        top:30px;
        left:0;
        background:#FFF;
        border:solid 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, .20);
        -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .20);
        z-index: 0;
    }
    /* AN ARROW LIKE STRUCTURE JUST OVER THE NOTIFICATIONS WINDOW */
    #notifications:before {         
        content: '';
        display:block;
        width:0;
        height:0;
        color:transparent;
        border:10px solid #CCC;
        border-color:transparent transparent #FFF;
        margin-top:-20px;
        margin-left:10px;
    }

</style>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).on("click", ".opendata", function () {

     var myuserid1a = $(this).data('userid1a');

     $(".modal-body_chat #b_userid1a").val( myuserid1a );
});


</script>


<br><br>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li id="noti_Container">
                <div id="noti_Counter"></div>   <!--SHOW NOTIFICATIONS COUNT.-->

                <!--A CIRCLE LIKE BUTTON TO DISPLAY NOTIFICATION DROPDOWN.-->
                <div style="color:white:" id="noti_Button">Click from notification menu</div>    

                <!--THE NOTIFICAIONS DROPDOWN BOX.-->
                <div id="notifications">
                    <h3>Notifications</h3>

<br><br>

<a href="#"   data-userid1a="11"  class="myBtn_chat opendata">click to Display Value Now</a>


                    <div style="height:300px;"></div>
                    <div class="seeAll"><a href="#">See All</a></div>
                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>



<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // ANIMATEDLY DISPLAY THE NOTIFICATION COUNTER.
        $('#noti_Counter')
            .css({ opacity: 0 })
            .text('7')              // ADD DYNAMIC VALUE (YOU CAN EXTRACT DATA FROM DATABASE OR XML).
            .css({ top: '-10px' })
            .animate({ top: '-2px', opacity: 1 }, 500);

        $('#noti_Button').click(function () {

            // TOGGLE (SHOW OR HIDE) NOTIFICATION WINDOW.
            $('#notifications').fadeToggle('fast', 'linear', function () {
                if ($('#notifications').is(':hidden')) {
                    $('#noti_Button').css('background-color', '#2E467C');
                }
                else $('#noti_Button').css('background-color', '#FFF');        // CHANGE BACKGROUND COLOR OF THE BUTTON.
            });

            $('#noti_Counter').fadeOut('slow');                 // HIDE THE COUNTER.

            return false;
        });

        // HIDE NOTIFICATIONS WHEN CLICKED ANYWHERE ON THE PAGE.
        $(document).click(function () {
            $('#notifications').hide();

            // CHECK IF NOTIFICATION COUNTER IS HIDDEN.
            if ($('#noti_Counter').is(':hidden')) {
                // CHANGE BACKGROUND COLOR OF THE BUTTON.
                $('#noti_Button').css('background-color', '#2E467C');
            }
        });

        $('#notifications').click(function () {
            return false;       // DO NOTHING WHEN CONTAINER IS CLICKED.
        });
    });
</script>



<br><br>

<a href="#opendata"   data-userid1a="11"  class="myBtn_chat opendata">click to Display from the body</a>



<!-- The Modal  chat menu starts-->



<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal_chat {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content_chat {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close_chat {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close_chat:hover,
.close_chat:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header_chat {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
height:10%;
}
.modal-body_chat {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    max-height: calc(100% - 25%);
    overflow: auto;
}
//.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer_chat {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
postion:fixed;
height:15%;
}
</style>




<div id="myModal_chat" class="modal_chat">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div  class="modal-content_chat">
    <div class="modal-header_chat">
      <span class="close_chat">&times;</span>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body_chat">

<input type="text"  name='b_userid1a' id='b_userid1a' >

    </div>
    <div style="" class="modal-footer_chat">
    info 
    </div>
  </div>

</div>



<script>
var modal_chat = document.getElementById('myModal_chat');
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close_chat")[0];
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn_chat");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++)
  btns[i].onclick = function() {
    modal_chat.style.display = "block";
  }
span.onclick = function() {
    modal_chat.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal_chat) {
        modal_chat.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>








<!-- The Modal  chat menu ends-->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the code below

```
$('#notifications').click(function () {
            return false;       // DO NOTHING WHEN CONTAINER IS CLICKED.
        });
```

According to the author of the script, the above function says Do nothing when the container is clicked. To this effect when the link is clicked, it does not display any data. thus removing the above script solved my problem. Thanks